# Loading being displayed in mobile jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using mobile jquery for a phonegap application. The problem that I am facing is that I see a "loading" message being displayed. My custom.js is absolutely blank. As soon as I exclude mobile jquery, the "loading" message is not displayed.

The page I am talking about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ohterisale</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-mobile.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="back">
                <a href="index.html" data-transition="slide" rel="external"><img src="img/back1.png"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Ohterisale
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

custom.js is blank.

Screenshot of the output :
http://codeoholic.com/iOSSimulatorScreenshot.png

Comment: Can you provide some more details, code, etc.?

Comment: have you added JQM css ?

Comment: you have anything like $.mobile.loading('show'); in your pageshow events?